# Change property using a loop

Tags: vb.net, loops

I was wondering if there is a way to compress my code using a loop, this is my code :
(Cell_1_Containes is a RichTextBox)

```
    Cell_1_Containes.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(MyLocation + "\Main\Cells\Cell 1\Containes.txt")
    Cell_2_Containes.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(MyLocation + "\Main\Cells\Cell 2\Containes.txt")
    Cell_3_Containes.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(MyLocation + "\Main\Cells\Cell 3\Containes.txt")
    Cell_4_Containes.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(MyLocation + "\Main\Cells\Cell 4\Containes.txt")
    Cell_5_Containes.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(MyLocation + "\Main\Cells\Cell 5\Containes.txt")
    Cell_6_Containes.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(MyLocation + "\Main\Cells\Cell 6\Containes.txt")
    Cell_7_Containes.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(MyLocation + "\Main\Cells\Cell 7\Containes.txt")
    Cell_8_Containes.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(MyLocation + "\Main\Cells\Cell 8\Containes.txt")
    Cell_9_Containes.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(MyLocation + "\Main\Cells\Cell 9\Containes.txt")
    Cell_10_Containes.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(MyLocation + "\Main\Cells\Cell 10\Containes.txt")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Edit your question to show your efforts/attempts.

Comment: if you put all your cell objects into a List or array structure, then you can loop over them to set their text (and use a counter variable for varying the number of the folder inside the path string)

Comment: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the place to go if you want a review and or looking for alternatives to your working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim cells() As Control = {Cell_1_Containes, Cell_2_Containes,Cell_3_Containes,Cell_4_Containes,Cell_5_Containes,Cell_6_Containes,Cell_7_Containes,Cell_8_Containes,Cell_9_Containes,Cell_10_Containes}
For i As Integer = 0 To 9
    cells(i).Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(MyLocation, $"Main\Cells\Cell {i+1}\Containes.txt"))
Next
```

Comment: IMHO, there's more than a few ways to do this, your approach works, but at the same time is restricted. If user adds more controls all of this would in turn have to be re-written. I would have voted on the question TBH as we help with specific issues, not code review.